# Simple use PHP to get data from XML

Tags: php, xml

I am getting some variable where is XML file, I can't edit it or do anything with it.

So what I do:

```
$xml = $client->get_details('WF0GXXGBBG7P857BB');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
//print_r($xml); 
$vin = $xml->vin; 
print_r($vin);
```

If I uncomment `print_r($xml)` it just prints out whole xml and works cool (output is http://pastebin.com/w5VVysZU), but if I use second part with `print_r($vin)` it just displays just SimpleXMLElement Object ( ),

Any idea what can I do? How can I fix this? I've tried like 20 tutorials and always get no output or error with using nonobject something.

**EDIT 1:**
I need it to display one specific thing from this XML, in example it's VIN, so from this big amount I want script to find where is `[vin] => WF0GXXGBBG7P857BB`  and echo `WF0GXXGBBG7P857BB`

**EDIT 2:**
My XML: http://pastebin.com/1KLB5Ba0

Comment: You just told us what happens, but there is nothing inyour question that explains what you would like it to do instead

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML elements can and have to be type casted to strings if you want to display them that way. Otherwise, as you seen, it just tells you that it is an object.

```
$vin = (string) $xml->vin; 
// OR
print_r((string) $vin);
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for answer, unfortuantely it display just blanked page

Comment: @JurajPolak Can you add your XML content (or a shortened version) to your question so we can see why ?

Comment: Added, also you can find output of print_r there which should be similar or atleast usefull

Comment: @JurajPolak I can't run codes atm and your XML is being displayed messily for me, but I'd say that it's because you're not "pointing" to the right node. SimpleXML requires you to get to the correct path with Object/Method chaining. Try this : `$xml->claim-history->request->vin` (I'm not sure how the '-' in claim-history is being handled though.)

Comment: I am not the author of this XML and i have to work with it (no choice) so unfortunately i cant do anything about it. Anyway `$xml->claim-history->request->vin;` display error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` on arrow from history to request So yea it probably dont know what to do with `-`

Comment: i try to use something like:`$route['claim-history'] = "claim_history"; `

but i get notice: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` anyway

Comment: @JurajPolak If nobody else manages to help you, I'll give a deeper look on your XML once I get back to my computer. It's weird that method chaining on XML elements is returning this error

Comment: Thanks mate, please can i get some other contat on you as well?(it will be more problematic to get here later)

Comment: Looks you didnt find a time for that, pitty